# Solving this simple simultaneous equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do I solve these two equations:
$\frac{x}{x+y} = \frac{1}{2}$ and $\frac{y}{x+y} = \frac{1}{6}$ ?

I tried reducing the first one and end up getting $x = y$, clearly my maths is pretty dusty

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Notice that $$\frac{x}{x+y}+\frac{y}{x+y}=\frac{x+y}{x+y}=1$$ but $$\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{6}\neq 1$$

Comment: I did notice that. What is one to do?

Comment: @edd91 That is a contradiction, hence no solutions.

Comment: Oh, thats very sad

Answer (score 4):

Turn it to a linear form

$$2x=x+y,\\6y=x+y.$$

But then,

$$x=3y$$ and substituting,

$$6y=3y+y$$ or $y=x=0$, which is not allowed.